# Passing single input parameter with format 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

My stored procedure has the following code:

```
WHERE tag IN (@InValue)
```

I want to send a list of tags as an input parameter

```
EXEC dbo.TestSelect @InValue = '''Test1'',''Test2'',''Test3'''
```

am I close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) - these have been introduced in SQL Server 2008.

> Table-valued parameters are a new parameter type in SQL Server 2008. Table-valued parameters are declared by using user-defined table types. You can use table-valued parameters to send multiple rows of data to a Transact-SQL statement or a routine, such as a stored procedure or function, without creating a temporary table or many parameters.